# How to prettify urls in VueJS

Tags: vue.js, routes

I have a basic SPA with VueJS front end consuming an Express api.

Currently my resource routes are like `.../users/:id`

However, instead of eg `.../users/1,`

I want `.../users/sam-smith`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`:id` it is just parameter, you can change it to anything that you want, however you need to change it everywhere.

Let's say you have users like this:

```
[
  { id: 1, userName: 'Alice' },
  { id: 2, userName: 'Bob' }
]
```

And you route `...users/:id` calling something like this `GET ...backend/users/:id`, which is probably calls something like `DB.getUserById(id)` - this is a great approach, because it allows to avoid collisions - e.g. all uses will devinetely have different `id`.

If you want to change this - you should change all the way e.g.: `...users/:userName` -> `...backend/users/:userName` -> `DB.getUserByUserName(userName)`. And most important - you should make sure that all users have **different user names** to avoid collisions.

Comment: Wow. thought I tried that. thanks for the answer and not downvoting too!